# Add new option inside the Hyperlink window

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-2.0

The current options inside the Hyperlink window, used when inserting hyperlinks in a format area, are: **Type, URL, Title** and **Target**. 
Is it possible to add a new one to manage the link rel attribute (nofollow, sponsored, ugc)?

[image: Hyperlink window]

Comment: Possible, but would require you're own GUI extension. I did try this once a while back and basically rolled my own version of this pop-up, based on the one above. I got as far as triggering my pop-up and having the additional text field but got stuck trying to override the FormatArea.js file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Neil and Mark have noted, what you are looking for is a GUI extension extending the **FormatArea.js** and three other JavaScript and ASPX files:

- %Tridion Home%\Web\WebUI\Core\Controls\FormatArea\FormatArea.js
- %Tridion Home%\Web\WebUI\Editors\Base\Views\Popups\Link\Link.aspx
- %Tridion Home%\Web\WebUI\Editors\Base\Views\Popups\Link\Link.js
- %Tridion Home%\Web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Commands\FormatArea\InsertHyperLink.js

In the extended popup **Link.aspx** file in your extension, you would have to add the extra fields that you need. For example, if you need a field for the `rel` attribute add something like this:

```
 <tr id="rowRel" valign="middle">
    <td><asp:Literal runat="server" Text="Rel" />:</td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="FieldRel" style="width:100%" maxlength="250" tabindex="6" /></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
 </tr>
```

In the extended **Link.js** in your extension, add an event handler for all on change events of your new fields something like this:

```
Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.Base.Views.Popups.Link.prototype._onRelChange = function Link$_onRelChange(event) {
    var sourceElement = event.target;
    if (sourceElement) {
        this.properties.NewLink.rel = sourceElement.value;
    }
};
```

In the extended **InsertHyperlink.js** in your GUI extension, update the popup to display your extended Link.aspx like this and not the OOTB Link.aspx popup:

```
var popup = $popupManager.createDisposingExternalContentPopup(
   $config.expandEditorPath("/Views/Popups/ExtendedHyperLink/ExtendedHyperLink.aspx", 'ExtendedHyperLink'), 
   { width: 400, className: "popupdialog gradient" },
   { link: link, popupType: Tridion.Controls.PopupManager.Type.MODAL_IFRAME });
```

In the extended **FormatArea.js** in the getHyperLink function, get the value of the "rel" input field and set it to the rel property of `lHyperlinkObj` like this:

```
lHyperlinkObj.rel = getElementsAttributeValue(lSelectedElements, "rel", ["a"], lBoolCheckChildren, lCreatedMarkers);
```

And in the `applyHyperLink` function, set the rel property of the lHyperlinkObj to the selected rel value:

```
if (iHyperlinkObj.rel) 
{
    lSelectedElement.rel = iHyperlinkObj.rel;
}
else 
{
    lSelectedElement.removeAttribute("rel");
}
```

and

```
if (iHyperlinkObj.rel)
{
    lAttributes.rel = iHyperlinkObj.rel;
}
```

If you have extended all the above JS and ASPX files and have configured the `extensiongroups` and `groups` in your config file properly you should be able to have the `formatarea` updated with the value of the custom attributes.

[image]

**Note:** This has to be tested for cross domain scripting if XPM is used as Mark noted. Eric Huiza's blog post on GUI extensions here http://erichuiza.blogspot.com/2013/10/ui-extensions-ensuring-item-is-full.html is of great help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no OOTB way to add options into the existing dialog.

As Neil notes, if you try to extend the current pop-up you will have challenges extending the formatarea.js as there's no supported extension point to that file. Take into consideration also this needs to work with the xdm {cross domain methods} object for cross-domain scripting if you're using XPM.

Extend to your own extension with its own dialog and version for formatarea.js - noting that any hotfix/update to that .js file will likely need to be integrated into your version.