# How to change Default Names in Page/Component?

Tags: cme, sdl-tridion

[image]I have a requirement to change the "File Name" in SDL Tridion Page.

I have verified in CME Editors, it showing

<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Strings, FileName %>" />:

Where  this strings are declared? Thanks in Advance

SDL Tridion Version : 9.1.0

Comment: Welcome to Tridion StackExchange, your question or problem is not clear? could you please explain bit more details in the question,  what you are trying to do?

Comment: When we open any Page In Tridion, We are having fields like Name, File Name, Page Template, Page Scheema, .etc.. As per My requirement Need to Change "File Name"  to "Page Url" .

Comment: First of all why you want to change the product labels?

Comment: Apart from the fact that you shouldn't try to change the product itself, I don't think that changing "File Name" to "Page URL" is a good idea, because that is just not what it is; the "File Name" is *not* the Page URL; it is a (small) part of the Page URL Path.

Comment: Maybe this customer can create a Language Pack with their own string resources where everything is called by a different name?  Just joking :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would want to change the default "File Name" on a page, but to answer your question the value of the text is coming from the resources file - `Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Strings.resx`  in `%TRIDION_HOME%\web\WebUI\WebRoot\App_GlobalResources`.

[image]

There is no OOTB way to change the label value and it is not recommended to modify core files, so if you wish to update these values, what you are looking for is a GUI extension. You can find more information about GUI extensions here - https://docs.sdl.com/783502/696275/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/gui-extensions. Essentially, you would have to extend Page.aspx in `%TRIDION_HOME%\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Views\`. This answer should also help you - https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/20661/1587.